# Trouble using Visual Studio to publish Docker image to GitLab container registry

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, gitlab

I'm using `VS 2017 15.7.3` with Docker enabled for an ASP.net core 2.1 project that has been committed to a private gitlab server I'm running on site. I turned on the registry features of GitLab and I can connect to and login to the server from my box.

So, with regard to VS2017, I created a new solution (`Solution1`) that shares its name with my GitLab repo. I have configured the publish settings for this project with my credentials and the push location of `https://mygitlabserver.example.com:4567/solution1/solution1/`.

The profile type I selected is `Container Registry->Custom`. I'm trying to push out an image for the first project in the solution (`Project1`). I have not modified the VS project properties Package tab settings, so the package ID remains the same as it started - `Project1`.

When I publish, I get a generic error in a tmp file in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` whose contents are as follows:

```
System.Exception: Running the docker.exe push command failed.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.Publish.ContainerRegistryProfileVisual.<PostPublishAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

I confirmed I can tag this image with Docker on the command line with the above URL and push it out successfully. I'm not sure if VS2017 has some other settings I need to use, but the documentation is light for working with a private server - they seem to be pushing Azure and I'm finding very little documentation outside of this.

Can anyone give any guidance or the location of more detailed logfiles?

Comment: I am getting a similar exception. Any updates? Log :: System.Exception: Running the docker.exe login command failed.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Azure.Publish.ContainerRegistryProfileVisual.<PostPublishAsync>d__24.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0):

Location of log files
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp